# Hot Swap Tray patents

Tags: licensing, design-patent, us8243435, us20100309621

A lot of rackmount server case are equipped with hot-swappable tray. 
Rackmount case brand might have different design of hot-swappable tray but the mechanical engineering can be actually or almost the same.

I have no experience with engineering and the prototype will probably be built by Manufacturer in China. The engineer will come up with the the locking mechanism design somehow.

Does the locking mechanism has to be different that is not patented? but the tray design will be quite different.

Example:

https://www.google.com/patents/US8243435

https://www.google.com/patents/US20100309621

Comment: This site can help you locate prior art or patent information, but you need to provide specific patent number(s) and a clearer question so others can help find an answer.

Comment: @RonJ. I have updated my question a bit more clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the claims. If all of the claims require an A, a B and a specific lock design C  and you build an X a Y and a C you haven't made something that falls within the words of the claim. But if one of the claims **only** includes the lock then you can't make that lock.